# StringBuilder.append alternative

Tags: java

Hi can someone suggest to me how I can refactor this code from using x.append and use only appened ( removing the x. every time). Thanks

```
StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
x.append("\n.O/");
x.append(fields.nextToken()); 
x.append("/");
x.append(fields.nextToken()); // Date
x.append("/");
x.append(fields.nextToken());
x.append("/Y");
```

Comment: You mean like `x.append(...).append(...)...`?

Comment: The technical term is _method chaining_. Since `StringBuilder#append` returns the same `StringBuilder` instance, you can continuously call `.append()` multiple times without the use of a semicolon between statements.

Comment: Why not `"\n.O/"+fields.nextToken()+"/"+fields.nextToken()+"/"+fields.nextToken()+"/Y"`? Compiler will generate StringBuilder code for you.

Comment: I'd do `String.format("\n.O/%s/%s/%s/Y", fields.nextToken(), fields.nextToken(), fields.nextToken());`

Comment: Note that @ElliottFrisch's suggestion wouldn't be safe in C, where order of evaluation of parameters is unspecified, but is good in Java, because order is guaranteed to be left to right.

Comment: @Pshemo: not in 9 or higher; now `+` on `String` uses an invokedynamic that was added to the JVM

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 True (more info: https://openjdk.org/jeps/280). But that is even more reason to use concatenation instead of StringBuilder, since JVM will most likely use just as good or even better code for it (at least for simple cases like one described in question, where we are not building big string in a loop).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the specific code you're looking for is just

```
StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
x.append("\n.O/")
  .append(fields.nextToken())
  .append("/")
  .append(fields.nextToken()) // Date
  .append("/")
  .append(fields.nextToken())
  .append("/Y");
```

There are several other -- arguably better -- approaches to writing this code, but you specifically asked for chaining the append statements.